# How to split file in 320KiB Multiples

Tags: linux, bash, split, backup, onedrive

Good Evening,

I have a linux server and want to backup it to OneDrive for business. My problem is that the file size changes each day and I need to split it in 320KiB multiples.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Felipe Liberman Fuchs

Comment: This is a very broad question. If you want help on StackOverflow you should first try to solve the problem yourself and then ask specific questions about problems you might be having with your solution.

Comment: What about `man split`?

Comment: 320 *KiB*? Are you backing up to floppy disks?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` to split big file into small pieces. More detail refer to [split manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html)

One example :

- I have one tar file, named "test.tar.gz", which is "25M";
- use `split` to split it into 3M small files;

  ```
  split -b 3M test.tar.gz pdf
  ```

  ~you can change 3M to 324K~
- result is :

  ```
  $ ls
  14474.pdf  pdfaa  pdfab  pdfac  pdfad  pdfae  pdfaf  pdfag  pdfah  pdfai  test.tar.gz
  $ du -sh *
  3.0M    pdfaa
  3.1M    pdfab
  3.0M    pdfac
  3.0M    pdfad
  3.1M    pdfae
  3.1M    pdfaf
  3.1M    pdfag
  3.1M    pdfah
  908K    pdfai
  25M test.tar.gz
  ```

Comment: Hi,</br>Thanks for your reply. </br> I need to split it in 320KiB Multiples. Do yo have any idea of how to do it?

Comment: Just change 3M to 324K. You can split your file into 320KB small multiples.